# Is there a way to convert an object to JSON in the smart contract?

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.cdt

I want to convert a series of data/object/struct into a json text before saving it into my table.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to/from JSON could take a long time. Blockchain transactions need to be very fast (<30ms).  Recommend not doing this.

If you want to do it, you need to provide your own JSON encoder/decoder in your contract.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit new to C++ and have thought the references I was seeing were JSON when in actuality, it might have been a vector of objects/classes. 

Others who might be looking for the answer might need this info so I'll just leave this here. Thanks again @Matthew Darwin!